# Bash Script Write File Out Depending on Contents

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file and it's in the form:

```
Thread1.Action1, wahhhhhh
Thread1.Action1, blahhhhhh
Thread1.Action2, wooooooo
Thread1.Action2, weeeeeee
Thread1.Action2, baaaaaaa
Thread2.Action1, mooooooo
Thread2.Action2, wooooooof
```

What I need to do is:

Write a file, where the filename is the first bit before the comma. This file should then contain all lines associated with it. e.g: There should be 4 files in this case: Thread1.Action1.out, Thread1.Action2.out, Thread2.Action1.out and Thread2.Action2.out

For example, **Thread1.Action2.out** should contain:

```
Thread1.Action2, wooooooo
Thread1.Action2, weeeeeee
Thread1.Action2, baaaaaaa
```

**Thread2.Action1.out** should contain:

```
Thread2.Action1, mooooooo
```

etc..

Note: I want it to be agnostic to the name of the first column - e.g: I won't necessarily know what the data is in the first column before executing the script, but there will be groups of it...

I want to write a bash script that will be able to do this. I've tried doing bits of it in awk, but it's getting very messy.

Any help?

Comment: Please show your attempts. You might be close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{print > $1".out"}' your_file
```

For your comment:exceute the below command for creating all the directories at the same time:

```
awk -F. '{print $1}' your_file | sort -u | xargs mkdir
```

Now execute this command:

```
awk -F, '{split($1,a,".");print >a[1]"/"$1".out"}' your_file
```

Comment: `awk` is a beast! :) ⁺¹!

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done it. Didn't realise it would be so easy!! If I wanted to modify it a bit, so that it created the files in a directory where the directory is the Thread. part, how would you do that? e.g: Thread1.Action1.out and Thread1.Action2.out are in directory Thread1 etc...

Comment: Then i guess you can write a wrapper shell script for checking whether the directory exist around this command. If its not there create the directory and then execute the command else simple execute the command.

Comment: Trying: mkdir < `cat inputfile | awk -F. '{print $1}' | uniq | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'` I get an "ambiguous redirect" error?

Comment: My bad, didn't need the < redirect!

Comment: I have the directories created based on the above statement, so I have directory Thread1, Thread2, but how do I now get your awk statement to write to those directories based upon the filename/column1 name?

Comment: Good one! Note you can also use `awk -F[,.] '{print > $1"/"$1"."$2".out"}'` for the directory part.

Comment: `print > $1".out"` is ambiguous/undefined and will be interpreted differently by different awks on different systems. You MUST parenthesize anything on the right side of an output redirection symbol `>` to avoid nasty surprises so in this case it'd be `print > ($1".out")`.